# How to load data from external file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

I am attempting to use AJAX in jQuery to load content to a div, however, it is severely failing:

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#webdev').hide();
     $("#apply-webdev").click(function() {
        var form = $("#webdev");
        var formContent = form.find("#webdev");
        form.slideToggle();
        $.ajax({
            url: "api.php?do=get_form_webdev",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                form.html(data.params);
        },
        dataType: "json"
      });
  });
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="rbutton"><button title="Apply for position" id="apply-webdev" onclick="load_webdev_form()">&nbsp;Apply&nbsp;</button></div>
    <div id="webdev">
    <fieldset><legend>Apply for position</legend><div style='padding:10px; text-align:center'><img src='/images/load.gif'/></div></fieldset>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

### **EDIT**

Below is the new code, based on answers given in this thread:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#webdev').hide();
    $("#apply-webdev").click(function() {
        $("#webdev").slideToggle();
        $("#webdev").load("api.php?do=get_form_webdev");
    });
    $('#webdevcancel').click(function()
        {
            $('#webdev').hide('slow');
        }
    );
    $('#webdevsave').click(function()
        {
        $('#webdev').block({ 
        message: '<h1>Processing...</h1><img src="/images/load.gif" /><br /><br />', 
        css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
    });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: var formContent = customize.find("#webdev"); <--- what's customize?

Comment: @Lior, I've just fixed that, the original in my script is customize, but I'm making it more general, so I renamed it to form.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is being return in data.Params.  It would be best if you could get the value via Firefox+Firebug.  Could it be that data.Params is undefined?

Comment: @Chris, I'm trying to, but Firebug keeps crashing Firefox :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to load content into an element in jQuery is the [load method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback):

```
$("#webdev").load("api.php?do=get_form_webdev");
```

Comment: are you sure that visiting api.php?do=get_form_webdev get you any result, can you give the full url here. it's strange for load function not to work

Comment: currently, it's pulling the stuff off, http://thestudentroom.com/api.php?do=get_widget_customize_all, however, for purposes, I have used "api.php?do=get_form_webdev". 

http://thinkteen.co.uk/volunteer is where all of this is happening in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the success function below, shouldn't you be using form.html(data.params) instead of formContent.html(data.params)?

> success: function(data) {
>                   formContent.html(data.params);
>           },

Comment: fixed, but still not loading the external content

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it is severely failing"?
I'd tried to set the dataType to html and use the data without the params like `form.html(data.);`